# Can't install MercurialEclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Classic 3.6.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.6.
I followed the instructions at http://javaforge.com/project/HGE#download.
I don't know what "CodeBeamer" is, but I presume it's necessary, so I did a "Select All".
Here's what I got:

> Cannot complete the install because
>   one or more required items could not
>   be found.   Software being installed:
>   codeBeamer Eclipse Studio (with Mylyn)
>   3.1.0.v201011161842 (org.codebeamer.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
>   3.1.0.v201011161842)   Missing requirement: codeBeamer Eclipse Studio
>   (with Mylyn) 3.1.0.v201011161842
>   (org.codebeamer.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
>   3.1.0.v201011161842) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
>   3.3.0' but it could not be found

I don't know where to find the required items, either. Is Eclipse Classic not good enough? Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plugin requires mylyn plugin which is included in [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2) or [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2). [Eclipse Classic](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-362/heliossr2) doesn't include it.

Comment: Thanks. I installed Mylyn in Eclipse Classic, and that works.